# Can not use \u in python

Tags: python, unicode-escapes

I am newbie in python so bear with me, I am learning python from 'Learn Python The Hard Way', I learned about escape sequences but I am not able to use \u.
I have tried `print "\U0001F47E"` , `print "U\U0001F47E"` , `print "U'\U001F47E'"`, `print 'u"\U0001F47E"'` but all print the string within quotes as it is, I have tried `print "\x56"` and other with \x they all are working fine. I also looked at https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/strings.html but I did not find anything that can help me.

So please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Unicode strings begin with u'...try that and that should fix your problem...

Comment: Why have you wrapped the fourth one with extra single quotes? It would have given you the correct result if you hadn't.

Comment: Please stop LPTHW if at all possible. First off, it teaches you Python 2, which is the outdated version of the language - essentially *all* new projects nowadays use Python 3. More importantly, its method of teaching, well, sucks. Read [this](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints) for more issues. There are many much better tutorials out there, starting with the official one on python.org.

Comment: For example, in Python 3, you don't have to worry about this garbage of putting `u` characters before some strings, but not others. Also, check the version of the docs you're reading - 2.5 was released in **2006**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode strings begin with "u"...try that and that should fix your problem.

you were on the right track here:`print 'u"\U0001F47E"'`

except you don't need the single quotes.
so... `print u"\U0001F47E"`

Comment: Can you write complete command so that I get what should be exactly typed.